# How can I generate these signals in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, simulink

The signals are:
[image]

Tb is bit time = 0.001s. Basically, first is square wave with 50% duty cycle and second is with 100 percent duty cycle. I tried using Pulse Generator, it is not giving me negative output and it does not let me choose 100 for duty cycle.

How can I do this in Simulink?

Comment: you've drawn a few step functions (e.g., for any time after `T_b`, the signal maintains a value of 0), but your explanation of those signals seems to indicate that the signals are *periodic* (e.g., every `T_b` seconds, you have the same pattern); is this true?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Yes, that's correct. The signals are periodic with period T_b and continues after. it's not zero after T_b.

Answer (score 1):

Behold, the Simulink model that generates the first signal:

[image: Simulink model]

The amplitude of the <kbd>Pulse Generator</kbd> is set to `2/sqrt(Tb)`, the duty cycle to 50%, and the period to `Tb`, where `Tb` is a variable in the (model) workspace.

As for the second graph; a square wave with 100% duty cycle:

[image]

There is, of course, no difference between a constant-valued signal and a square wave with 100% duty cycle, which is what Simulink nags about. I don't know why the Mathworks decided to explicitly forbid 100% duty cycles from <kbd>Pulse Generator</kbd> blocks, but oh well.

Comment: @Rody_Oldenhuis Thank You.